# Is there a way of showing content in a Statamic antlers template if a user is authenticated?

Tags: laravel, statamic

I'm having some issues trying to get some content to display in an admin panel when a user is logged into it. I am using Antlers templates in Statamic with Laravel in there  too and can't find a template tag that could be used for checking if the user is authenticated?

I've tried looking at the Statamic documentation but couldn't find anything that I think would have helped me with this.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a user is logged in and display content based on this condition within an Antlers template, you can use the {{ user }} tag or its aliases. Here’s a simple way to do it:

```
    {{ if user }}
    <!-- Content to display if the user is logged in -->
    <p>Welcome back, {{ user:name }}!</p>
{{ else }}
    <!-- Content to display if the user is not logged in -->
    <p>Please <a href="/login">log in</a> to access the admin panel.</p>
{{ /if }}
```

Comment: Is the {{ user }} tag the user for the Statamic admin panel or for the authenticated user on the Laravel application. I need it to be for the Laravel application?

Comment: In the context of Statamic, which is built on Laravel, the {{ user }} tag typically refers to the currently authenticated user in the Statamic control panel, which is part of the Statamic CMS